# Save text from javascript variable to .txt file

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying this code, but can't get it to work, it says "The name "text" does not exist in the current context"

```
CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("for(var i = 0; i < elems1.length; i++){ var textt = elems1[i].innerText}");

        string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(docPath, "WriteLines.txt"), true))
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine(textt);
        }
```

How can I make variable "textt" accessible?

Here is a full code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("var elems1 = document.getElementsByClassName('question-text')");
        CurBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("for(var i = 0; i < elems1.length; i++){var textt = elems1[i].innerText}");
        

        string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(docPath, "WriteLines.txt"), true))
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine(textt);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to use `ContinueWith()` after `ExecuteJavaScriptAsync()` but are you sure about your loop in JavaScript? `for(var i = 0; i < elems1.length; i++){var textt = elems1[i].innerText}` will override `textt` value with each loop so the only last value will be stored in it.

Comment: @Jax-p Yes, I am sure, because after I click the button, I refresh a page manually, and then new text shows up and I wan to click the button again to repeat the script

Comment: `textt = elems1[elems1.length - 1].innerText` will give you the same result. Only one value will be set. Are you sure you don't want to concatenate (`text += someString`) these strings instead?

Comment: @Jax-p I edited it, removed "for(var i = 0; i < elems1.length; i++)", thanks. It's okay, i can use it like this, I just wanna know how to access this "textt" variable from outside

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [`ContinueWith()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netcore-3.1) which can be chained after `ExecuteJavaScriptAsync()`.

In this example you need to use your JavaScript code as a function which returns anything (ex. textt). So I've created something like this:

```
var myScript = @"(function () {
    var textt = "";
    var elems1 = document.getElementsByClassName('question-text');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems1.length; i++){
        textt += elems1[i].innerText
    }
    return textt;
})();";
```

than I asynchronously evaluate it and catch the result which I am returning from that function:

```cs
var result = await CurBrowser
   .GetMainFrame()
   .EvaluateScriptAsync(myScript)
   .ContinueWith(t => {
       var result = t.Result; // your textt
       string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
       using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(docPath, "WriteLines.txt"), true)) {
            outputFile.WriteLine(result);
      }
   });
```

this is just a suggestion of how it might work.

Comment: I am getting "a local or parameter named 'result' can not be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define local or parameter"

Comment: Ok, sorry. Rename it or delete it's declaration. It ain't needed anyway. Edited Q.

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: In this instance I'd suggest using just the ContinueWith,  there's no need for the await and the extra result variable is problematic.

Comment: @amaitland can you edit the code and paste it here, please?

Comment: and await either. but still, variable result causing issues, "missing ) after argument list", source: about:blank (3)"

Comment: Start with something basic and work your way up see https://gist.github.com/amaitland/9d354376960b0cd9305a#file-oneplusone-cs